# kernel panic error

Tags: kernel

I am not able to run any application, due to the fact that my computer hangs, saying "kernel panic". I tried to start the computer in recovery mode, without success. I tried to upgrade the kernel, but still nothing changed.

I don't have a bootable CD or a drive, and also I am unable to transfer my data to an external hard disk due to errors.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and successfully run Ubuntu after choose а other (older) kernel version from GRUB menu. Option under recovery mode. After update and restart my system, last kernel version startup normality without error.
Sorry for my english :)